# Gmail displaying email messages with html codes

Tags: php

I have a little piece of code for sending email messages that can cater html codes. The message displays perfectly in hotmail, however in gmail, all the html codes were just regarded as text and displayed.

Below is the code format:-

```
$headers        = "From: $from \r\n <$email_return>"; 
$headers        .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

ob_get_contents(); ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $email_message;?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<div style="text-align:left;"><img src="sitelogo.png" height="50px;"></div>
<br>
Dear <?php echo $name;?>,
<br><br>
Thanks!

<br><br><br>
<strong><i><?php echo $email_signature;?></i></strong><br><br>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
$mail_sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo $mail_sent ? "OK!!" : "not OK!!";
}
?>
```

I wonder if I can do anything to the php codes for proper display, otherwise I may have to give up the html format. Thank you.

Comment: What, if anything, is in `$headers`?

Comment: I pasted it also, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `quoted-printable` instead of `7bit`?

Also there are no standard HTML tags and you're starting with a `div`.

Also try placing the text/html content first.

**Update**

> In general, user agents that compose multipart/alternative entities
>   should place the body parts in increasing order of preference, that
>   is, with the preferred format last. For fancy text, the sending user
>   agent should put the plainest format first and the richest format
>   last. Receiving user agents should pick and display the last format
>   they are capable of displaying. In the case where one of the
>   alternatives is itself of type "multipart" and contains unrecognized
>   sub-parts, the user agent may choose either to show that alternative,
>   an earlier alternative, or both.
>
> NOTE: From an implementor's perspective, it might seem more sensible
>   to reverse this ordering, and have the plainest alternative last.
>   However, placing the plainest alternative first is the friendliest
>   possible option when mutlipart/alternative entities are viewed using a
>   non-MIME- compliant mail reader. While this approach does impose some
>   burden on compliant mail readers, interoperability with older mail
>   readers was deemed to be more important in this case.

From:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

It also looks like you're not declaring a MIME version in your headers. eg.
`MIME-Version: 1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It was not really an issue with Gmail or with PHP. The issue, in my case, was that when PHP generated the email message from my PHP source file, like the one above, it interpreted the  end of lines in some way that Gmail did not like, perhaps it sent a LF instead of CRLF, some thing like that. I did not look at the details. What I know is that, given that the default on my emails was CRLF for an end of line, I wrote explicitly all end of lines using `<?php echo "\r\n"; ?>`, instead of relying on empty lines in the file and then Gmail interpreted correctly the message. It is likely that the issue was specific to the editor I used to write the PHP source file. In my case it was Notepad++. Perhaps it was not configured properly. It does not matter, now,  just to be on the safe side, I always explicitly enter the end of lines in my email messages, at the least for the part that must be understood by MTAs and MUAs, the Content-Type, the boundary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps to fix it: (Worked for me)

```
Hold down the Shift key and click the Reload button
Press "Ctrl + Shift + R" (Windows,Linux)
Press "Command + Shift + R" (Mac)
```